# htaccess redirection subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Hi I am looking to the following in .htaccess:
RewriteRule ^pqr$ /pqr.php

[without 301 redirect, because I want the user to see "pqr" in the broswer and not "pqr.php"]

The problem is that when I try the above .htaccess code, /pqr automatically redirects to the "pqr" subdirectory (/pqr/).  I'm looking for a way to stop that automatic redirection.

Do you know how to do that with htaccess?
my current htaccess code

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /Wordpress_Work/placewise/wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /Wordpress_Work/placewise/wordpress/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Answer (score 0):

That should do it:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Still doesnt seems to work for me
Accessing /pqr still redirects to pqr directory(/pqr/)
its wordpress and want to access the pqr.php with /pqr no trailing slash as there is directory named pqr there as well , so /pqr shows content of /pqr.php but shows as /pqr

Comment: I really don't understand your comment. Why do you even want to do that if you are using wordpress? And why do you want to access a directory and a file with the same name and the same URL?

Comment: i just want to access a php file which has same name as of my old folder. For better URL as old folder has been replaced with new php file

Comment: The easiest way is to use the old folder and place an index.php file in it.